# Create instance using Snapshot

Tags: google-compute-engine

My compute engine instance is in a zone that went on maintenance yesterday.
Fortunately, a month ago I created a snapshot of my persistent disk.
Now I would like to create a new instance in a different zone (not currently in maintenance).

When I create that new instance and choose to create the disk from my snapshot, no problem.
But when I try to ssh into this new instance, I get a time out.

Answer (score 0):

Is this possibly a disk created from an image before Compute Engine went GA (mid December 2013)? If so, you will need to [upgrade the kernel](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/transition-v1#customkernelbinaries) before it will boot using the v1 API.

Answer (score 0):

What i think the problem here is : the SSH keys aren't copied rather tagged for newly created instance.
This is because, in Google-Cloud - if you take snapshot of disk, it takes snapshot of only the BOOT-DISK data, not the metadata like ssh-keys, tags of original-instance, network configs etc.

So, you may need to add SSH metadata keys for that instance or use tags for assigning the keys & then you should be able to do SSH to the newly created instance.